# Can banished items appear in chests?

Tags: vampire-survivors

Bainshing an item removes it a a level up option for the rest of the run. Does banishing an item also prevent it from being upgraded by treasure chests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banish removes it from treasure chests as well.

It can still be levelled or gained from stage pickups.

More Info:
https://vampire-survivors.fandom.com/wiki/Banish